# How much percent the string match the regex

Tags: php, regex

Basically, I just wondering if exists a function like this:

```
$string = 'helloWorld';

// 1 uppercase, 1 lower case, 1 number and at least 8 of length
$regex = '/^\S*(?=\S{8,})(?=\S*[a-z])(?=\S*[A-Z])(?=\S*[\d])\S*$/'

$percent = matchPercent($string, $regex);

echo "the string match {$percent}% of the given regex";
```

Then, the result could be something like this:

> the string match 75% of the given regex

Seeing another post and question, I can do somehitng like this:

```
$uppercase = preg_match('@[A-Z]@', $password);
$lowercase = preg_match('@[a-z]@', $password);
$number    = preg_match('@[0-9]@', $password);
```

But, the goal is to work with any regex pattern at the function

Comment: It's unlikely it exists - regexs have the capacity to be so complicated (with look-aheads/behinds and nested capturing sub-patterns) it might be hard to calculate a percentage match anyway.

Comment: Not an answer, but maybe a starting point: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php

Comment: IdoNotNeedCodeAsHomeWork() || justAnPossibility()

Comment: Do the strlen of the matched part Vs the strlen of the whole string ?

Comment: @TecBrat, can you post your comment as answer please? I suppose that I can pass a third parameter as an example word and then compare it!

Comment: Regex is the wrong tool for this job. Regexes either match or they don't match; they don't "75%" match.

Comment: @meagar, and how do you know what is exactly the job I do? (kindly asking to you)

Comment: @manix I know you have already chosen a solution, but Big H and I had pretty much the same idea, so if you're interested please see mine for a slightly different implementation.

Comment: @zx81, you give me a hard lesson: never accept and answer so soon.

Comment: @manix Ha thank you but that's not a worry, Hamza deserves to soar to the skies... Just wanted to draw your attention to a different way of counting the percentage. Thanks for your support, wishing you a great day. :)

Comment: I didn't think my comment was good enough to be an "answer", but thought it might still be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do it the regex way and based on the use-case you've provided, we need to make the whole regex optional. Also we'll be using capturing groups in our lookaheads.

But first things first, let's improve your regex:

- `[\d]` is redundant, just use `\d`.
- `\S*(?=\S{8,})` remove `\S*` part, we already have it at the end.

Our regex will look like `^(?=\S{8,})(?=\S*[a-z])(?=\S*[A-Z])(?=\S*\d)\S*$`

Now is the tricky part, we will add groups in our lookaheads and make them optional:

`^(?=(\S{8,})?)(?=(\S*[a-z])?)(?=(\S*[A-Z])?)(?=(\S*\d)?)\S*$`

You might ask why? The groups are made so that we can track them later on. We make them optional so that our regex will always match. That way, we can do some math!

```
$regex = '~^(?=(\S{8,})?)(?=(\S*[a-z])?)(?=(\S*[A-Z])?)(?=(\S*\d)?)\S*$~';
$input = 'helloWorld';

preg_match_all($regex, $input, $m);

array_shift($m); // Get rid of group 0

for($i = 0, $j = $k = count($m); $i < $j; $i++){ // Looping
    if(empty($m[$i][0])){ // If there was no match for that particular group
        $k--;
    }
}

$percentage = round(($k / $j) * 100);
echo $percentage;
```

<kbd>[**Online php demo**](https://eval.in/144753)</kbd>

Comment: Awesome presentation! I was just starting to work on something very similar, and you beat me to it. :D +1

Comment: Well... I do not know what to say haha. So grateful!

Comment: Arggh... slightly different but you beat me to it. :) You're the man.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** I see that Hamza had pretty much the same idea.

Sure! That's a really fun question.

Here is a solution for a simplified validation regex.

```
$str = 'helloword';
$regex = '~^(?=(\S{8,}))?(?=(\S*[a-z]))?(?=(\S*[A-Z]))?(?=(\S*[\d]))?.*$~';

if(preg_match($regex,$str,$m)) {
    $totaltests = 4;
    $passedtests = count(array_filter($m)) -1 ;
    echo $passedtests / $totaltests;
}
```

Output: 0.5

**How does it work?**

1. For each condition (expressed by a lookahead), we capture the text that can be matched.
2. We define `$totaltests` as the total number of tests
3. We count the number of tests passed with `count(array_filter($m)) -1`  which removes the empty groups and Group 0, i.e. the overall match.
4. We divide.

Comment: I'm actually surprised: I didn't know that php "supports" optional lookaheads. [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/bS5vG0) complains about it not being quantifiable.

Comment: @Hamza regex101 complains about many things... I gave a solution yesterday where it sounds like the guy thought it was wrong because it didn't work in regex101, even though it executes in native code. :)

Comment: @hamza But anyhow for practical purposes I'm sure you agree that it doesn't make a difference whether we make the lookahead optional or the test being assessed... Perhaps yours is more readable without the two `))`

Comment: Indeed on that note I chose for `preg_match_all()` to make it dynamic. Anyways do not forget to remove the `i` modifier, you overwrote my edit :P

Comment: @hamza Thanks, I didn't know how to see your edit as the system told me there was an edit in the middle of my adding the explanation. I often put in `(/i)` for convenience while testing but you are absolutely right, it doesn't belong here.

Comment: I agree with regex101: there's no excuse for optional lookaheads, whether your flavor of choice supports them or not.  I know you're only using them for the side effect of filling (or not filling) the capturing groups, but why bother?  You still have to use program logic to interpret the result of the match, so why not do a separate, *simple* regex match (or other test) for each condition?  That applies to @HamZa's answer, too; they both suffer from excessive cleverness.

Comment: @AlanMoore I quite agree with you. I would not use something like that myself... but it's fun to try and rise to the challenge of answering this question within the specs. :) Cheers, -zx