# The best way to match at least three out of four regex requirements

Tags: javascript, regex

In password strategy, there are 4 requirements.
It should contains any three of the following

1. lower case.
2. upper case.
3. numeric.
4. special character.

The following regex will match all cases

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]).{4,8}$
```

I know I can use '|' to declare all combinations, however, that will produce a supper long regex. What is the best way to replace '|'  so that it can check if the input contains any of three conditions in the combination?

Comment: you mean this `^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*?[_\W]).{4,8}`

Comment: Why not just keep it simple for readability and use 4 different regexes?

Comment: unclear for me. Could you provide some valid and invalid matches?

Comment: @PandaYang why do you limit it with 8 chars?

Comment: @AvinashRaj invalid: "Panda" "panda123" "panda!!!" "PANDA123" valid: "Panda!" "panda123!" "PANDA123!"

Comment: Which regex flavor are you running?

Comment: Possible near duplicate: [How much percent the string match the regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23398552/how-much-percent-the-string-match-the-regex)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a PCRE flavor, the following one could suit your needs *(formatted for readability)*:

```
^(?:
    ((?=.*\d))((?=.*[a-z]))((?=.*[A-Z]))((?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]))|
    (?1)      (?2)         (?3)                             |
    (?1)      (?2)                      (?4)                |
    (?1)                   (?3)         (?4)                |
              (?2)         (?3)         (?4)
).{4,8}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

One-lined:

```
^(?:((?=.*\d))((?=.*[a-z]))((?=.*[A-Z]))((?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]))|(?1)(?2)(?3)|(?1)(?2)(?4)|(?1)(?3)(?4)|(?2)(?3)(?4)).{4,8}$
```

Demo on [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/W986nY7mLiuhfwws)

---

JavaScript regex flavor does not support recursion (it does not support many things actually). Better use 4 different regexes instead, for example:

```js
var validate = function(input) {
    var regexes = [
        "[A-Z]",
        "[a-z]",
        "[0-9]",
        "[^a-zA-Z0-9]"
    ];    
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0, n = regexes.length; i < n; i++) {
        if (input.match(regexes[i])) {
            count++;
        }
    }    
    return count >=3 && input.match("^.{4,8}$");    
};
```

Comment: Doesn't recursion make it take longer to match? How is this "the best way"? Also, the first line looks like a candidate to be within a `(?DEFINE` block.

Comment: @Unihedron With one single regex, I'm afraid there is no better way. The best way would be to use 4 different regexes: much more readable and not necessarily less efficient. `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group.

Comment: @sp00m Thanks, but I am using javascript. And I think the logic is the same as using original but just replacing with group number.

Comment: @PandaYang I asked you which flavor you were using, but your did not answer. This is not compatible with JavaScript, since it does not support regex recursion. See my edit.

Comment: @sp00m sorry man, I didn't see your question. Yes, I found out that. It seems regx doesn't have the method to do such that intelligent thing.

Comment: @PandaYang Correction: JS regex is weak compared to PCRE regex. I would suggest to use different regexes in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, here's a method which uses a slight modification of the same regex, but with a short bit of code authoring required.

```
^(?=(\D*\d)|)(?=([^a-z]*[a-z])|)(?=([^A-Z]*[A-Z])|)(?=([a-zA-Z0-9]*[^a-zA-Z0-9])|).{4,8}$
```

Here you have five capturing groups - Check whether at least 3 of them are not null. A null group for capture effectively indicates that the alternative within the lookahead has been matched, and the capturing group on the left hand side could not be matched.

For example, in PHP:

```
preg_match("/^(?=(\\D*\\d)|)(?=([^a-z]*[a-z])|)(?=([^A-Z]*[A-Z])|)(?=([a-zA-Z0-9]*[^a-zA-Z0-9])|).{4,8}$/", $str, $matches);

$count = -1; // Because the zero-eth element is never null.
foreach ($matches as $element) {
    if ( !empty($element)) {
        $count += 1;
    }
}

if ($count >= 3) {
    // ...
}
```

Or Java:

```java
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(...).matcher(string);

int count = 0;

if (matcher.matches())
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        if (null != matcher.group(i))
            count++;

if (count >= 3)
    // ...
```